# The member with identity '' does not exist in the metadata collection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-api

Não consegui encontrar como resolver esse problema entre a minha base e o meu mapeamento usando Fluent API.

Eu tenho um mapeamento no Fluent API de uma determinada tabela pré existente na base de dados do cliente, porém esta tabela possui uma *trigger* que é disparada no momento do *insert / update*, toda vez que executo meu teste de inserção ele dá o erro informado no titulo.

Já tentei fazer isso:

```
Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

mas não resolveu.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações, pois costumamos mantê-las o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [Bate-papo do Stack Overflow em Português](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [Stack Overflow em Português Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/) :)

Comment: Coloque na sua pergunta o relacionamento, indique as informações referentes a esse `insert/update`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu náo posso demonstrar aqui a trigger por conta da confidencialidade do projeto, a unica coisa que da pra dizer é que o no código legado não há problemas com a trigger ela funciona perfeitamente, eu só quero entender porque o mapeamento fluent que fiz para todas a outras entidades funcionam e para essa não da erro de identity por conta da trigger

Comment: problema resolvido, identifiquei que a trigger tinha um select de retorno que e o sistema não tinha um campo para receber o resultado desse select

Answer (score 1):

A trigger retornava um select e o mapeamento não esperava um retorno e por isso estava dando o erro